# why does ls -p give different result for command-line and bash file

Tags: bash, ls

From a bash command line, running ls -ldp on a link to a directory

```
ls -ldp /var/www/cgi-bin/PLACENAMES
```

gives

```
 /var/www/cgi-bin/PLACENAMES -> PLACENAMES-BIGSUR/
```

with trailing slash as expected.

But using same command in bash script file gives

```
/var/www/cgi-bin/PLACENAMES -> PLACENAMES-BIGSUR
```

i.e. without slash

Makes no sense to me. Would like to get useful info the slash provides in my script.

Cannot see anything in man page to cover this.
Running Ubuntu GNU bash, version 5.1.16

Responding to comments here:

bash script file uses #! /bin/usr/bash
I tried changing to #! /bin/bash  but no change

script  : type ls => ls  is /usr/bin/ls
command : type ls => ls is aliased to `/bin/ls --color=auto'

Noting 'ls' difference above, tried specifying both /usr/bin/ls and /bin/ls in script, instead of simple 'ls' I'd been using, both gave the same result (sans end /)

environment has LS_COLORS but no other 'LS' variable

script file results cited come from 'set -vx' output

---

Script+Output:

```
!#/usr/bin/bash                                                                                   
set -vx
/usr/bin/ls -lpd /var/www/cgi-bin/PLACENAMES

347 test.ls-p.sh
/usr/bin/ls -ldp /var/www/cgi-bin/PLACENAMES
3 /usr/bin/ls -ldp /var/www/cgi-bin/PLACENAMES
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jack jack 17 Jan 17  2015 /var/www/cgi-bin/PLACENAMES -> PLACENAMES-BIGSUR
```

Comment: What is the output of `type ls` in the command line and in the bash file?

Comment: Bet you have an alias that adds `-F` to `ls` options.

Comment: a bit confusing because if you are running bash, then bash IS the command line. presumably you mean in a script, which could be using a different shell (what is the shebang?) But ls is a standalone program so path or alias may be different

Comment: And if the output of the command told by KamiCuk is an alias with `$LS_OPTIONS`, what does contain this variable?

Comment: Try: `\ls -lp`.

Comment: [Alias are not expanded in non-interactive shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1498) (i.e. when a script is run), unless it is explicitely set on with `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Comment: @Amessihel And even if that's enabled, the alias may not be defined in the script process.

Comment: @Barmar, yes it depends on where the alias is defined

Comment: Except in restricted circumstances (which don't apply when the `-l` option is used) the output of `ls` cannot be parsed reliably so `ls` should normally  not be used in shell programs.  The problem described in the question demonstrates one of the reasons.  See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Responded to comments in edited post (too long for comment)

Comment: Are you _sure_ you did not change the symlink between? symlink pointing to `-> a` and `-> a/` are two distinct symlink values. Please post the output of `readlink -f /var/www/cgi-bin/PLACENAMES`. `script file results cited come from 'set -vx' output` Please copy  full output of the script and command line with `set -x`.

Comment: @KamilCuk - added to OP

Comment: @pjh - that link refers to _parsing_ the ls output, particularly for multiple files.  Cannot see that applies here to the _output_ from the ls command.

Comment: pluse-uno for follow up on debugging questions! It seems a similar question has come up before, but I don't know what you would use as a search target relating to a trailing `/`! Good luck!

Comment: @shellter People understandably thought problem must be something in my setup rather than ls+bash, needed to demonstrate that was not the case

Comment: yes, understood and hence my pluse-uno. Compare to many who reply with that info in comments or not at all or repeat their original information with nothing new or "problem description" = "It's not working!" .. Keep posting and good luck!